# C# Date Time Comparison Issue

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to load a series of files into my C# application which are created after 8am but before 4pm. However when I do this no files are loaded. I have checked all file creation times and they are all created at 8:03am. I was wondering if anyone has an explanation for this and a possible way to resolve the issue.

```
DateTime arg1 = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8);
DateTime arg2 = DateTime.Today.AddHours(16);

var filesToRetrieve = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, fileType)
    .Where(d => DateTime.Compare(new FileInfo(d).CreationTime.Date, arg1) > 0 
    && DateTime.Compare(new FileInfo(d).CreationTime.Date, arg2) < 0);

files = filesToRetrieve.ToArray();
```

Comment: You could try to first get all the files and then filtering them in seperate lines. in that way you can go through them with the debugger and see if the values are there.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, your datetime constructors are invalid: `new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.AddDays.Day, 8, 0, 0);` Is it supposed to be: `new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 8, 0, 0);`

Comment: That code does not compile, what is `DateTime.Today.AddDays.Day` supposed to be?

Comment: Are you sure you need UTC, not local time ?

Comment: If you want to use `4pm today` and `8am today` you can simplify the expression to: `DateTime arg1 = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8); DateTime arg2 = DateTime.Today.AddHours(16);`

Comment: I've tried with both UTC and local time without the desired result. Sorry I had AddDays in as I was attempting to load in files from the previous day as well. I have edited the code so that it now compiles.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with FileType.

Comment: @Nexuz Put `Directory.GetFiles` in a separate variable. Then carry out linq stuff on it. Debug it see if the variable with `Directory.GetFiles` is empty or not.

Comment: Something like `new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month` etc. is an antipattern. What if the time changes in the middle of that statement? It might be 1ns before midnight on New Year's Eve when you get Month and Year from `DateTime.Today` then midnight on the first when you get Day. You'd end up with 1st December 2015! Keep `DateTime.Today` in a local variable, **then** use it.

Comment: Or better yet, `DateTime.Today.AddHours(8);` as LasseV.Karlsen suggests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you use the `CreationTimeUtc`, UTC time, while both `arg1` and `arg2` are local time. So instead of using `CreationTimeUtc`, I would suggest you use the `CreationTime`.

Furthermore, you don't need the `Date`.

```
var filesToRetrieve = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, fileType)
    .Where(d => DateTime.Compare(new FileInfo(d).CreationTime, arg1) > 0 
    && DateTime.Compare(new FileInfo(d).CreationTime, arg2) < 0);
```

If we write `arg1.Date`, we get the date component of this instance. The time component of the `DateTime` we get, when we usethe `Date`, is 00:00:00.That being said, I think that now is clear why you didn't get the expected result, while you had done the change regarding the UTC.

Comment: I have changed CreationTimeUtc to CreationTime and I am still not able to load any files. I would expect a total of 12 files to be loaded as that's what's contained in the folder yet none are loaded.

Comment: You don't need the `Date`.

Comment: By removing Date from the end of CreationTime has helped to resolve the issue. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

arg1 and arg2 are not in UTC time, while your comparisons are in UTC. To prevent problems with files created in different time zones and created at the start or the end of the Daylight Saving Time season, I'd suggest to use always UTC times and only convert it to local times if humans must read it.

Consider the use of property Date:

```
DateTime arg1 = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
```

Also consider the use of DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles. This method already gives you a sequence of FileInfo objects.

And why not use the smaller-than operator:

var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory, fileType);
   var filesToRetrieve = dirInfo.EnumerateFiles()
        .Where(fileInfo => arg1 < fileInfo.CreationTimeUtc.Date 
                        && fileInfo.CreationTimeUtc.Date < arg2);

The nice thing about enumerateFiles is that it used deferred execution. If you don't need all elements from the sequence the enumerateFiles doesn't iterate over more statements then you need. For instance if you only need the First() or Any(), or  Take(3) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write your code like this:

```
string
    sourceDirectory = @"C:\TEMP",
    fileTypes = "*.*";
DateTime
    dtFrom = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(8),
    dtTo = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(16);

var filesToRetrieve = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory)
    .GetFiles(fileTypes, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(fi => fi.CreationTime >= dtFrom && fi.CreationTime <= dtTo);

var files = filesToRetrieve.ToArray();
```

... and as Christos pointed out, you're comparing UTC to Local time. This will yield in unexpected results, unless your timezone is UTC or GMT!

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment above I tried with and without UTC without the desired result. Thanks to @Christos I have managed to resolve the issue.